# Multiple List with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

Let say That I have an Array of arrays like so:

```
var arrays = [["one", "two", "three", "Four"], ["four", "five", "six"]]
```

My goal is to create a list for each child of each subarray then navigate to the next child.

```
Example 1: one -> (NavigationLink) two -> (NavigationLink) three -> (NavigationLink) Four. 

Example 2: four -> (NavigationLink) five -> (NavigationLink) six.
```

Each arrow is a NavigationLink between each List.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let arrays = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F", "G", "H"]]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(arrays, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink( destination: DestinationView(items: item)) {
                        Text(item.first!).font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Dash")
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView : View {
    
    var items: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink( destination: DestinationView(items: items)) {
                    Text(item).font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, you have `DestinationView` linking to another `DestinationView`. Does this imply that there could be an arbitrary number of levels of data? Because the example set is only 2 levels deep.

Comment: @jnpdx Yes exactly. Each subarray won't necessarily be equal. How do you think I could achieve that?

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted. I'm still a little unclear on what the desired output is for each step of the list, but I gave an answer a shot. Happy to adjust if you clarify the intent of what each stage should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this by slicing the array each time you pass it to the `DestinationView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let arrays = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F", "G", "H"]]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(arrays, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink( destination: DestinationView(items: Array(item[1..<item.count]))) {
                        Text(item.first!).font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Dash")
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView : View {
    
    var items: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            if self.items.count > 0 {
                NavigationLink( destination: DestinationView(items: Array(items[1..<items.count]))) {
                    Text(items[0]).font(.subheadline)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is calling DestinationView from DestinationView good practice? I mean, is there anything bad about the approach? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: I’m wondering the same thing as John, any way I think it will depend on its practicality… and context.